# EXC_BAD_ACCESS using ARC when poping back to view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access

to begin with, here is some code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    FirstViewController *first = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    MBPullDownController *pullDownController = [[MBPullDownController alloc] initWithFrontController:first backController:second];
    [self.navigationController addChildViewController:pullDownController];
}

- (void)pushAnotherViewController:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    AnotherViewController *another = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"anotherViewController"];
    [self pushScheduleViewController:another];
}
```

I use the **MBPullDownController** open source control. Using to seperate view controllers I load into the pull down controller. This code is in a view controller called *RootViewController* which is embedded in a *UINavigationController*. Then there's a method for pushing another view controller in the navigation controller. It's when I try to use the method (in *AnotherViewController*) `popToRootViewController:` that my app crashes and the EXC_BAD_ACCESS message comes up in the console.

**EDIT**

This is my code in "AnotherViewController"

```
- (void)popBack
{
    RootScheduleViewController *root = [[RootScheduleViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:root animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: That means you're accessing an object that is no longer in memory, turn on `Enable Zombie Objects` in your scheme to track down what object your accessing and that should help you identify what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Just to make sure, you `popToRootViewController` from the `navigationController`, not `anotherController` itself, right? What object does it EXC_BAD_ACCESS on?

Comment: I do 'self.navagitationController'. *** Assertion failure in -[UINavigationController popToViewController:transition:] and *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a bad access error when you call `popBack` because you are creating a new instance of the view controller and then trying to pop to it. For a navigation controller, the view controller must be part of the navigation stack in order to pop to it. So if an instance of this view controller exists, find it in the navigation stack and pop to it.

```
for(UIViewController * viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers){
  if([viewController isKindOfClass:[RootScheduleViewController class]]){
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:viewController animated:NO];
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: That pushes the pull down controller to the navigation controller, it's the "AnotherViewController" I want to push and then be popped back to when a button is clicked. The 'addChildViewControll:' works great for adding the pull down controller to the Root View Controller.

Comment: Edited the question to include "pop" method.